# Being told to update apache due to Vulnerabilities

Tags: 16.04, updates, apache2, lts, vulnerability

we are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)..

Yesterday, I got an email from our main computing body asking us to upgrade Apache due to vulnerabilities in version 2.4.43 and prior: https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html

I know the package versions of Ubuntu are different than the latest and greatest and I am wondering if I am secure in the version I am running or if I need to update somehow other that installing security updates on Ubuntu.

Am I safe from these vulnerabilities?

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can check the changelog for security patches:

http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.15/changelog

Look there and see if the fixes have been applied.

Answer (score 0):

If your upstream can enumerate the CVE(s) that they are worried about, you can search https://ubuntu.com/security/notices using either the package name or the CVE.

That search will tell you what the Ubuntu Security Team has done (or plans to do) about the disclosed vulnerability, and which releases of Ubuntu (if any) are affected. If already patched, it will tell you the patched version number so you can make sure that you have it.